# IIS url rewrite to https for multiple domains, but not all

Tags: iis, https, url-rewriting, iis-8

i have +10 domains on one solution, and about half of them have had an SSL certificate attached. I seem to have trouble creating ONE rule to make the correct ones being forced onto https.

I can to a rule for each of them, but feel this should have worked:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect 1" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainNo1.dk$" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainNo2.dk$" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainNo3.dk$" />
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

this leaving the domain4, domain5, etc. alone.

Unfortunately it does not kick in when I have more than one domain in the rule. I'm guessing it is the logical grouping that is probably default:

```
logicalGrouping="MatchAll"
```

But setting:

```
logicalGrouping="MatchAny"
```

will make the sites not work at all. After the redirect to https it continues to redirect the pages, resulting in "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

I would have thought this was handled by

```
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
```

But no.

Hope anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below rewrite rule to match multiple domains:

```xml
<rule name="http to https with multiple domain name" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.sample1.com|www.sample3.com" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

[image]

Comment: looks promising. I'll give it a go!

Comment: Perfect! Just the solution i needed, but I did not know you could do ORs in the condition. Thanks.